# Null pointer exception while using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, nullpointerexception

I am using Hibernate and spring. this is my model class

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "CSI_TARGET", 
        query = "select * from CSITARGET('CSIINDEX',2)",
        resultClass = CSITarget.class)})
public class CSITarget {


    @Column(name="csi_target")
    private BigDecimal csi_target;

    @Id
    @Column(name="financialyearfrom"  ,nullable = true)
    private int  financialyearfrom =0;

    @Column( name="at_yearhalf" , nullable = true)
    private  String at_yearhalf = "";

    public BigDecimal getCsi_target() {
        return csi_target;
    }

    public void setCsi_target(BigDecimal csi_target) {
        this.csi_target = csi_target;
    }

    public int getFinancialyearfrom() {
        return financialyearfrom;
    }

    public void setFinancialyearfrom(int financialyearfrom) {
        this.financialyearfrom = financialyearfrom;
    }

    public String getAt_yearhalf() {
        return at_yearhalf;
    }

    public void setAt_yearhalf(String at_yearhalf) {
        this.at_yearhalf = at_yearhalf;
    }
```

I am using Hibernate to call a stored procedure in postgres database. The stored procedure returns a table which is mapped to this model class. Now my problem is, the table that is returned from the database contains a null value. I am in the need of doing some manipulations on the data. Now since the null value is mapped to the bean class I am getting a null pointer exception. How can I make hibernate ignore the null values in the database and set a default value for the corresponding property in the bean class.  As you can see I have used nullable property also. It does'nt work.

Comment: Is `at_yearhalf` or `financialyearfrom` `null`? Well, they are allowed to be. I recommend your logic to handle null values for the fields that can have the value. Another (not good solution IMO) is to use the getters and setters to check for null and replace the value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am retrieving a list of data. In that list for eg the third value (record in the db) is null, there I am getting the exception. If I do some try catch I cant manipulate the remaining data in the table. Can I?

Answer (score 2):

`financialyearfrom` is `int` which cannot be assigned `null` value though corresponding column you might be having `null` value in database if column is defined as nullable.

For handling null values in java primitive variables, remove `nullable=true` and possible add default value 0, so all null value from db column would convert to 0 or 0.0 etc.

Or

Use wrapper class instead i.e. `Integer` which will allow you to retain null value assigned from db column.

Again, above two approaches are in general applicable for primitive variables using in `Hibernate` entities.

Further to add `@ID` column shouldn't be nullable IMO, if it corresponds to primary key column (in most of the cases it is) so your code would be wrong as primary key column doesn't allow `null` values.

Comment: No. I tried all the above ideas. I dont know why it didnt work out. I gave a default value for that particular property, but still it gets the null value and throws me a null pointer exception. I still have one doubt. Using wrapper class accepts null value? If it accepts still null pointer exception will occur while I am accessing the getter of that property. Right?

Comment: Atlast I somehow tried to give some value for the null record in the database. Now there is no option of null pointer exception. But my question still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use COALESCE in your query to assign a default value to that field if its null?  If that's possible that's probably the best way to fix this issue w/o having to tweak your code too much.